# How to add numbers using multiple threads?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

I'm trying to add the numbers in a range eg. 1 to 50000000. But using a `for-loop` or `reduce(_:_:)` is taking too long to calculate the result.

```
func add(low: Int, high: Int) -> Int {
    return (low...high).reduce(0, +)
}
```

Is there any way to do it using multiple threads?

Comment: so let me guess what you are doing. You want the function to return sum of all the intergers in range `low` to `high`. am I correct ?

Comment: Do this inside the background thread.```DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                //Your code
            }```

Comment: see this for help : https://getswifty.dev/create-your-own-bigint-in-swift/

Comment: @Arsenic Right.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I want to solve it using multithreading.

Comment: @PGDev - multi threading also takes time, then you can go with concurrency or await concepts, may be its helps u, but my suggestion is goo with bigInt concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a series of integers does not amount to enough work to justify multiple threads. While this admittedly took 28 seconds on a debug build on my computer, in an optimized, release build, the single-threaded approach took milliseconds.

So, when testing performance, make sure to use an optimized “Release” build in your scheme settings (and/or manually change the optimization settings in your target’s build settings).

But, let us set this aside for a second and assume that you really were doing a calculation that was complex enough to justify running it on multiple threads. In that case, the simplest approach would be to just dispatch the calculation to another thread, and perhaps dispatch the results back to the main thread:

```swift
func add(low: Int, high: Int, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let result = (low...high).reduce(0, +)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(result)
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like so:

```swift
add(low: 0, high: 50_000_000) { result in
    // use `result` here
    self.label.text = "\(result)"
}

// but not here, because the above runs asynchronously
```

That will ensure that the main thread is not blocked while the calculation is being done. Again, in this example, adding 50 million integers on a release build may not even require this, but the general idea is to make sure that anything that takes more than a few milliseconds is moved off the main thread.

Now, if the computation was significantly more complicated, one might use `concurrentPerform`, which is like a `for` loop, but each iteration runs in parallel. You might think you could just dispatch each calculation to a concurrent queue using `async`, but that can easily exhaust the limited number of worker threads (called “thread explosion”, which can lead to locks and/or deadlocks). So we reach for `concurrentPerform` to perform calculations in parallel, but to constrain the number of concurrent threads to the capabilities of the device in question (namely, how many cores the CPU has).

Let’s consider this simple attempt to calculate the sum in parallel. This is inefficient, but we’ll refine it later:

```swift
func add(low: Int, high: Int, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let lock = NSLock()
        var sum = 0

        // the `concurrentPerform` below is equivalent to 
        //
        // for iteration in 0 ... (high - low) { ... }
        //
        // but the iterations run in parallel

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: high - low + 1) { iteration in
            // do some calculation in parallel

            let value = iteration + low 

            // synchronize the update of the shared resource

            lock.synchronized {
                sum += value
            }
        }

        // call completion handler with the result

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(sum)
        }
    }
}
```

Note, because we have multiple threads adding values, we must synchronize the interaction with `sum` to ensure thread-safety. In this case, I'm using `NSLock` and this routine (because introducing a GCD serial queue and/or using reader-writer in these massively parallelized scenarios is even slower):

```swift
extension NSLocking {
    func synchronized<T>(block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        lock()
        defer { unlock() }
        return try block()
    }
}
```

Above, I wanted to show the above simple use of `concurrentPerform` but you are going to find that that is much slower than the single threaded implementation. That is because there is not enough work running on each thread and we’ll do 50m synchronizations. So we might, instead, “stride” adding a million values per thread:

```swift
func add(low: Int, high: Int, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let stride = 1_000_000
        let iterations = (high - low) / stride + 1

        let lock = NSLock()
        var sum = 0

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterations) { iteration in
            let start = iteration * stride + low
            let end = min(start + stride - 1, high)
            let subtotal = (start...end).reduce(0, +)
            lock.synchronized {
                sum += subtotal
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(sum)
        }
    }
}
```

So, each thread adds up to 1 million values in a local `subtotal` and then when that calculation is done, it synchronizes the update of `sum`. This increases the work per thread and dramatically reduces the number of synchronizations. Frankly, adding a million integers is still no where near enough to justify the multithreading overhead, but it illustrates the idea.

---

If you want to see an example where `concurrentPerform` might be useful, consider [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948082/long-cycle-blocks-application/39949292#39949292), where we are calculating the Mandelbrot set, where each pixel of the calculation might be computationally intense. And we again stride (e.g. each iteration calculates a row of pixels), which (a) ensures that each thread is doing enough work to justify the multithreading overhead, and (b) avoid memory contention issues (a.k.a. “cache sloshing”).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to just return the sum to all integers in range from `low` to `high` then you can do it even faster with some simple maths

you can consider an [arithmetic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) starting from `low` and going to `high` with a common difference of 1 ,and have (`high - low + 1`) elements in it.

then the sum will straight up be :-

```
sum = ( (high * ( high + 1 )) - ((low * (low - 1)) ) / 2
```

Comment: Adding is just for example. I can be any operation on a large range of numbers.

Comment: @PGDev then you can check this out : https://medium.com/@prasanna.aithal/multi-threading-in-ios-using-swift-82f3601f171c